# How can I get a summary of data (mean, min, max, range--I'm working with weather data logged every 10 minutes) for each day of a time series?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics

So basically my data is the following: Data point `#`, `Date`, `Time`, `Temp` and `Salinity`. Loggers logged over 9 months, and I need to summarize each day by minimum temperature and salinity, as well as max, range, and mean. The number of data points are not consistent each day, because some data needed to be pulled out because the loggers became exposed in the intertidal. Any suggestions on code for this? Very new to R, but would like to use it as much as possible.

```
#   Date    Time    Temp°C  Salinity,ppt   
8   5/12/13 9:52    15.13   28.2187  
9   5/12/13 10:02   15.21   28.0135  
10  5/12/13 10:12   15.38   27.7348  
11  5/12/13 10:22   15.51   27.5082
```

Comment: Try search for `?aggregate` or `?tapply` in R. Also, because this question is not about statistics but rather how to manipulate a software, it may be moved to Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you don't need statistical advice on how to exclude exposed logger data, this question is probably [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Matters of coding within a particular software environment tend to get passed over to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) when they don't require special statistical knowledge.

Comment: This is also not especially suitable for SO, as it is a case of "please give me code". SO is focused on problems with posters' code; it is not a help line for people who need code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is focused on a code request.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate() may be a suitable solution:

```
mySummary <- data.frame(
aggregate(Petal.Width~Species, data=iris, min),
aggregate(Petal.Width~Species, data=iris, max),
aggregate(Petal.Width~Species, data=iris, mean))

mySummary <- mySummary[,c(1,2,4,6)]

colnames(mySummary) <- c("species", "min", "max", "mean")

mySummary
```

Results:

```
     species min max  mean
1     setosa 0.1 0.6 0.246
2 versicolor 1.0 1.8 1.326
3  virginica 1.4 2.5 2.026
```